# Does making class final help compile time be faster?

Tags: swift

I am wondering if a class is marked as a final, will it be compiled faster? I think no, because making class final helps only optimize Swift Method Dispatch.

Comment: Any such difference will be negligible (very very small). If you're really curious, why not go ahead and run a benchmark?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it does. Apple has given specific guidance in this regard.

As you yourself say:

> making class final helps only optimize Swift Method Dispatch.

Yes, so if this class has no subclasses, the compiler will make that optimization. But if a class is not explicitly *marked* as final, the compiler has to *look* for subclasses in every other file, because their existence changes how the details for this class are compiled (i.e. in order to make that optimization). And that search adds time and overhead.

So if you know that your class has no subclasses, always mark it final. On a large project in the real world, the difference is very noticeable.

Comment: But, why do you think it can help to reduce compile time, which means, build time also? I think it only helps to reduce run time, not compile or build time. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Are you asking me to say again, in a comment, what I already said in my answer? You don't have to like my answer, but please don't force me to repeat it.

Comment: Read your answer again and understood you already answered that. Sorry :(